# Symfony 1: Get app config parameters

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm writting tests and task for a new app for an application and I need to access to the "app config parameters" of this new app defined in `/apps/mynewapp/config/app.yml`. I thought it will be as easy as written in the Symfony doc, but it seems I've forgotten something.

When I get my config: `$actions = sfConfig::get("app_actions")` it is `NULL`. I thought the config name is wrong, but when I get all the config parameters available with `sfConfig::getAll()`, I don't have my app config parameters.

Maybe I've forgotten to include my `/apps/mynewapp/config/app.yml`?

There is the content of my file:

```
all:
    .array:
        actions:
            bind_destroy: BindDestroyAction
            bind_subscribe: BindSubscriptionAction
        messages:
            bind_destroy: BindDestroyMessage
            bind_subscribe: BindSubscriptionMessage
```

And there is how I try to access to my parameters in `/apps/mynewapp/lib/GRM/GRMSender.class.php`:

```php
class GRMSender
{
    private $actionClassNames;
    private $messageClassNames;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->actionClassNames = sfConfig::get("app_actions");
        $this->messageClassNames = sfConfig::get("app_messages");
    }
}
```

The class has already been autoloaded and I'm able to instantiate the class in my unit test scripts.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

The problem is about my tests (in `/test/unit`) and my tasks (in `/lib/task`). I have to use what I did in my application "mynewapp". I did some things :

- For the tasks, I defined the application in my task options :

  class mynewappActionTask extends sfBaseTask
  {
      protected function configure()
      {
          // Do some configuration...

  ```
      try {
      $this->addOptions(array(
          new sfCommandOption(
              'application',
              "app",
              sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED,
              'The application name',
              "mynewapp" // There
          ),
      ));
      } catch (sfCommandException $e) {}
  }
  ```

  }
- For the tests, I wrote a file which loads my mynewapp config. IMHO it's a hack and there is a better way to do it :

```php
$configMynewapp = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration("mynewapp", sfConfig::get("sf_environment"), true);
```

There must be better ways to get mynewapp config parameters in tasks and in tests. In mynewapp files (controller, lib, etc.) it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

/apps/mynewapp/config/app.yml

```
all:
  actions:
    bind_destroy: BindDestroyAction
    bind_subscribe: BindSubscriptionAction
  messages:
    bind_destroy: BindDestroyMessage
    bind_subscribe: BindSubscriptionMessage
```

Then you can get:

```
$actions = sfConfig::get('app_actions');
```

It will return:

```
$actions => array(
  'bind_destroy' => 'BindDestroyAction',
  'bind_subscribe' => 'BindSubscriptionAction'
)
```

Anyway, you can access one of them directly:

```
$action = sfConfig::get('app_actions_bind_destroy')
$action => 'BindDestroyAction'
```

Comment: Hello thx for your response. I'm sorry, I was too general in my question. My problem was about getting the configuration parameters of my application in my tasks and my tests. I found a solution for the task (adding the application to the task options) but for the tests I did a hack by loading my `mynewapp/config/app.yml`. When I'm a php file under "mynewapp" application (controlleur, lib, etc.) it's as you said. But in `/lib/task` and in `/test` Symfony seems to not load the application configurations unless we ask Symfony to do it. I don't find the proper way to load conf in `/test`...